# Is an integrated Wiener process recurrent or transient?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Like the title says, if I take an integrated Wiener process / Brownian motion $\int ^t _0 W_s ds$, will it be recurrent or transient? Or, under what conditions will it be one or the other?

I know that, for any $t$, the integral is a normal variable ~$N(0,\frac{t^3}{3})$. So it'll diverge to $\infty$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$. And it's not a martingale. But would it still be recurrent? And how would I show that, or show that it's not?

(If there are any theorems or discussions of this out there, even just a link to that would be great!)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by recurrent/transient? If, for example, the hitting time $\inf\{t>0: \int_0^t W_s\ \mathsf ds = 0\}$ is almost surely finite?

Comment: Roughly, yeah. Transient as in the probability of it returning to the starting state infinitely many times is 0. Or, equivalently, the probability of returning to the starting state in finite time $< 1$. (from https://brilliant.org/wiki/transience-and-recurrence/ )

Comment: Those properties are equivalent for a Markov process, but this process is not Markov.

Comment: @Math1000 What is a "hitting time"? The time it takes to achieve a particular value?

Comment: Given a (measurable) subset $E$ of the state space of a stochastic process $\{X_t:t\geqslant 0\}$, the hitting time of $E$ by $X$ would be e.g.
$$
\inf \{t>0: X_t\in E\}.
$$
(Assuming of course that $\mathbb P(X_0\in E=0)$ to avoid triviality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recurrent.
Let $X_t := \int_0^t W_s \,ds$. I claim that $\varlimsup_{t\to\infty}X_t=\infty$ and $\varliminf_{t\to\infty}X_t=-\infty$, so every real number is visited infinitely often a.s.

Here is a sketch of a proof.
Write $\mathscr F_t := \sigma(W_s ; s \le t)$. For a finite stopping time $T$, write $X_t = X_{t \wedge T} + (t - T)^+ W_T + Y_{(t - T)^+}$ with $Y$ a copy of $X$ that is independent of $\mathscr F_T$. Use $T_n := \inf \{t \ge n ; W_t = 0\}$ to see that $[\sup_t X_t = \infty]$ is independent of $\mathscr F_n$ for each $n$, whence is trivial: $P[\sup_t X_t = \infty] \in \{0, 1\}$. If this event has probability $0$, then
use $T := \inf \{t \ge 1 ; W_t = -1\}$ to see that $P[\inf_t X_t = -\infty] = 1$, which contradicts symmetry. Therefore, $P[\sup_t X_t = \infty] = 1$.

A stronger result was proved by Khoshnevisan and Shi,
Chung's law for integrated Brownian motion,
*Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **350** (1998), no. 10, 4253–4264.

In two (and higher) dimension, integrated Brownian motion tends to infinity: Kolokoltsov, A Note on the Long Time Asymptotics of the Brownian Motion with Application to the Theory of Quantum Measurement, *Potential Analysis* **7** (1997), 759–764.

Answer (score 0):

When reading about [Wiener processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) on Wikipedia, I encountered the statement: " Like the random walk, the Wiener process is recurrent in one or two dimensions (meaning that it returns almost surely to any fixed neighborhood of the origin infinitely often) whereas it is not recurrent in dimensions three and higher," which cited [Pólya's Random Walk Constants](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html). This page leads to a whole sort of rabbit whole of many things that are pretty unknown to a current student of stochastic processes.

In googling for an answer to this, I came across this question; so I suppose an indirect answer is one condition for Wiener process to be recurrent is that it must be one- or two-dimensional. Suffice to say I don't really understand why, though.

(I'm unsure if this would be better as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that anyway.)

Comment: It's true that a Wiener process is recurrent in dimensions 1 and 2, and transient in higher dimensions, but it's not clear how that helps answer whether the *integrated* Wiener process is recurrent or transient.

Comment: Great point, my eyes totally glazed over that detail. My response then is just-sort-of related.